# PHP value exists in array

Tags: php, arrays, exists

Okay here's the situation:

```
$x = array('yo'=>12,'go'=>13);
```

how do i test if a value is in the array or not?

for example:

```
isThereInArray(12) => True or 1 or whatever
isThereInArray(123) => False or 0 or null or -1 or whatever
```

Comment: Please check for existing questions/answers before you add a new one. :-)

Comment: sorry @middaparka i'll see to that next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will help you out here.

For more rapid development, consult the PHP documentation like so:

https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=find+in+array&lang=en&scope=quickref

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer! I'll accept the answer as soon as i can!

Comment: Some seconds difference :(